# Are specific energy levels the same distance away from the nucleus for all elements?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, orbitals, subatomic

Atomic radius decreases across a period, but does this mean specific energy levels are different distances away from the nucleus for different elements (eg- the 2nd energy level)?

Comment: Quantum mechanical orbitals extend through all space. There is no 'distance' from the nucleus per se. However, one can say something like that the 1s orbitals do scale with the charge on the nucleus.

Comment: @JonCuster so because they scale with the charge on the nucleus, the 1s orbital is NOT an equal 'distance' away for all element atoms?

Comment: Also, in a heavier atom, the presence of inner electrons modifies the potential well which confines the outer resonant standing waves.

Comment: @XXb8 - again, it is a space-filling wave function, but, on average, the 1s orbital around an otherwise bare nucleus (taking R.W. Bird's comments into account) will be 'closer in', but calling it one 'distance' is not right.

Comment: To summarize the comments of others, yes, $\langle r\rangle$ for each orbital does depend on the nuclear charge. Can you appreciate the [trends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radius#Explanation_of_the_general_trends)?